# JUnit Eclipse - Display stack trace on success

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4

I'm writing some unit tests in eclipse which expect exceptions to be thrown.

I wonder if there is an option to display the stack-trace when a test passes, it would be useful when you are writing test for the first time to check if the exception is been thrown really due to  the case you are testing.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do that.

Use the `@Test` annotation with an `expected` argument:

```
@Test(expected=MyAppException.class)
```

If the test does *not* throw the exception it's a test failure.

There should be an Eclipse view option to show test logging output, but in general, explicit logging from tests isn't valuable. You can also debug your test if you don't trust the JUnit annotations.

Comment: @carrizo if you additionally want to see stacktrace on console output, you could surround this test's code with try-catch and print stack trace from there, but don't forget propagating the exception up

Comment: Yep that's what I am doing but I was looking for an option to do it without having to write a try catch for each test.
Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @carrizo But what's the goal? Don't you trust that JUnit works?

Comment: The case is this, you have a XSD and no matter what's wrong with the xml you are validating it always throw the same exception and what really tells you the problem is the exception message, so if you write a test with @Test(expected=TheException.class) it will always pass.

That's why I use org.junit.rules.ExpectedException with a matcher to tell the message I'm expecting, but since JUnit doesn't give you the stack trace it is a pain the first time you write the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put System.out.print() statements inside the catch block of the test? I'm not sure how else you want to display output from a test because they are typically built to be silent when they succeed since there are so many of them.

Have you thought about using log4j and log.debug()?

Comment: Actually I'll try later to extend the JUnit annotation or something to enable this, it is a pain having to catch exceptions, log and throw it again for every test you write :/

Comment: We ran into the same issue testing our exception handling in a system many years ago. We never found a good solution but I remember hearing later versions of JUnit providing support for this.  I'd have to look through the JUnit docs.